# Change a extern variable from 2 C files

Tags: c

I want to be able to modify a variable from one C file and see the changes of that variable on the other one

Here are my C files:

file1.c:

```
#include "myheader.h"

int 
main( void )
{       
    printf("Variable %d\n", var);
}
```

file2.c:

```
#include "myheader.h"

int main(void){
    int var = 1;
    var = var + 1;
}
```

The header file looks like this:

```
extern int var;
```

Now, I want to run file2.c first and than when I run file1.c print the incremented value of var. Ideas?

I think I am doing everything like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c) answer, but can't make it work.

PS: Just started learning C.

Comment: Are you trying to make **two** programs that talk to each other, or are you trying to make **one** program that uses global variables?

Comment: from included link `...multiple source files linked together...`. By now you have two unrelated programs.

Comment: I didn't see the link. I'll answer my own question, you're trying to make one program that uses global variables. The place to start is the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433226/3386109) to that question.

Comment: @user3386109 I am trying to make two programs that talk to each other.

Comment: @Elsban Then you have a lot to learn and SO is not the right forum to teach you from scratch. You are looking for IPC (Inter Process Communication). Mechanisms include [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe), [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), [shared memory](http://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview) or even just files.

Comment: @kaylum I am a Java programmer so I was thinking like static variables work there. You can declare a static variable on a file and access and change it on another one. That is what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: There is no exact equivalent in standard C. What you can do is [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) a file in shared mode. Or use one of the other IPC mechanisms already mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your "files".c has a `main` function and thus will compile into a separate executable.

So you can't have one executable increment a variable in its *own* address space and then have another executable see the change in someone *else's* address space - the other executable will have an own variable in its own address space. Unless you would use advanced inter process communication (but that is Lesson 42).

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks a lot.